# Javascript Boolean Validation

Tags: javascript, string, boolean

My question is about boolean validation of below expression.

If you run `(!+[]+[]+![])` in your JS console, it returns us 'truefalse'.
How is it possible?  How does this logic work?

Comment: "Validation"???

Answer (score 0):

First part `!+[]` returns `true` as a Boolean. Second part `[]+![]` is `"false"` as String. Concatenating Boolean with String converts the result to string and gives you at the end `"truefalse"`.

Here is provided deep explanation to JSFuck
https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck#how-it-works